# Sylow $5$-subgroup in $S_{16}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Find two different $5$-Sylow subgroups in $S_{16}$.
>   *Hint:* use group multiplication.

Any hints?

Comment: I thought the definition of Sylow-p-subgroup is a subgroup of maximal $p$ power, i.e. maximal $k$ such that $p^k \Big | |G|$. In your question it seems to me there are higher powers of $5$ that divide $|S_{16}| = 16!$. Can someone point out to me what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Does conjugation work here? In this case we just need to find a 5-sylow subgroup of $S_{16}$ which is not normal which will fulfill the condition, don't we? If I miss something, please tell me, thanks. By the way, to type $S_{16}$ is better to use S_{16} instead of S_16 as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @Matt: where is the problem? the 5-sylow groups here will be of order $5^3$, cause 16! = ..5..10..15..

Comment: my bad, I read your question as if you were looking for subgroups of order $5$.

Answer (score 7):

What does a permutation of order 5 look like?

Can you give a condition when two permutations of order 5 commute?

Comment: well it can be a cycle of order 5, when they are disjoint?  should I look at the multiplication of 3 disjoint cycles of order 5, hm?

Comment: You should look at the multiplication of the three (cyclic) groups generated by these cycles, as indicated by your hint, noting that the generators mutually commute.

Answer (score 3):

Since $16!$ is divisible by $5^3$, but not $5^4$, the $5$-Sylow subgroups of $S_{16}$ are the subgroups of order $5^3$.

An example is
$$\langle (1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5), (6\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10), (11\ 12\ 13\ 14\ 15)\rangle.$$
(Since any pair of generators commutes, the group has isomorphism type $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$ and in particular order $5^3$.)

Another example is
$$\langle (1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5), (6\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10), (11\ 12\ 13\ 14\ 16)\rangle.$$

Both examples have a unique common fixed point of all elements.
In the first example, it is $16$, and in the second example it is $15$.
So the examples give two different $5$-Sylow subgroups of $S_{16}$.